# Reset user profile in Active Directory

Tags: windows, active-directory

I'm currently struggling with our Administrator profile on our local AD domain.

This profile is somehow corrupted but I cannot figure out how to reset that. This profile does not have a roaming profile and despite what everybody on the internet writes, there must be settings that get transferred onto a freshly installed computer and bork up the user profile. It must be some permission settings to the user folder or some registry entries.

I even copied the Administrator in the AD and made a new user with it and this one works fine.

Does anybody have an idea how I can reset this account to the default state so that it works correctly again? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: More information please.  For a start, am I right in thinking that you mean something goes wrong whenever you log into a domain computer with the built-in domain administrator account?  What are the specific symptoms?

Comment: ... does the problem also occur when the domain administrator account logs into the domain controllers?

Comment: @Harry Johnston I noticed the problems while installing a printer. When I try to open the printer properties then it tells me that I don't have the permissions for rundll.dll or when I press Troubleshoot then I don't have permissions for that and so on. The event viewer tells me about DCOM 10016 and other permission issues. I tried fixing that but it led nowhere. There are also other strange things that just don't work caused by unexpected permission errors.

Comment: But I cannot try this account on the domain controller since this is a 2008 R2 machine and the problems, as far as I've found out, are only when I use the new Windows 10 Settings. The same actions from the Control Panel do work.

Comment: Huh.  Just a guess, but this might actually be a bug in Windows 10 rather than a problem specific to your domain.  Microsoft probably never tested this scenario, since the usual practice is for the built-in domain administrator account to only be used on domain controllers, and only during the initial setup of the domain.

Comment: It worked fine for quite some time before this happened during one new installation :/ Would it be a problem if I delete this account and recreate it? Or is there some kind of reset switch (my initial question)?

Comment: You can't delete (or create) built-in accounts.  And there isn't any sort of reset for them either, I don't see any way to fix it without first figuring out what has actually gone wrong.  This really started happening simultaneously on all your clients?  Any chance it was caused by this month's updates?

Comment: Probably not. I was setting up a new computer (with latest updates)  and adding it to the domain and installing a few things and then it suddenly started happening. But honestly I may as well not have realized it earlier and it was there  all along. We get a new server in like 2 weeks and have not decided yet if we setup the AD freshly or not. This is probably decided now :/